# In Linux , how to monitor the progress of shell script during execution in remote server using ssh and expect

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, expect

I have below code in a shell script `connect.sh`. The remote script will take minimum 1 hour to complete the execution. I am able to see the output of the below script in `$local_dir/file.tmp` only after the remote script execution is completed where I have to wait for one hour.

How to monitor the output/progress of remote script parallely during execution?

cat `connect.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash 
local_dir="/scratch"

/usr/bin/expect > "$local_dir/file.tmp" << EOF

    set timeout -1
    spawn ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" "user@host" "cd /u01; ./remote_script.py arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4" 
    expect "user@host's password:"
    send "$pwd\r"
    expect "*#*"
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

The log will collect whatever `remote_script.py` prints. There will be buffering, so if it only prints a few lines, you will not see them until the job finishes, or until the writer forcibly flushes the buffers.

As a workaround of sorts, maybe change `remote_script.py` so that it prints progress reports to standard error.  The Python `logging` module makes this straightforward and intuitive.

```
import logging

def main():
    logging.info('Starting up ...')
    # Do startup stuff
    for n in range(100000):
        if n % 10000 == 0:
            logging.info('Progress: {0}/100000'.format(n))
        # do more things in each iteration

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
        format='%(module)s:%(asctime)s:%(message)s')
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

expect has to buffer its output in order to match patterns.

You can define the buffer size and take action when the buffer fills. Like this:

```
set match_max 4096    ;# or some other value, not too small
expect {
    full_buffer {
        puts -nonewline "."
        fflush stdout
        exp_continue
    }
    "#" {puts ""}
}
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

This <strike>will</strike> *should* print a dot for each 4K of data seen , a kind of progress bar. But you haven't shared how much data the remote script generates, so this is really a stab in the dark.